# how do i reference a checkbox in my options menu from my main activity in android?

Tags: android, menu, checkbox

i have an option to "mute" in my menu options like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<PreferenceScreen
 xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<CheckBoxPreference android:summary="Mute all sound effects" android:title="Mute"android:key="muteSound"></CheckBoxPreference>
</PreferenceScreen>
```

now how can i check if that checkbox is checked or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to get the [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html):

```
//in the main activity you should set the default values in case user has never entered the preferences screen
PreferenceManager.setDefaultValues(this, R.xml.preferences_file, false);
preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
```

and then read the value:

```
preferences.getBoolean("muteSound", true) //the second argument is the default value
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the following in an `Activity`:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
boolean muteSound = prefs.getBoolean("muteSound", false);
```